# Why my SQL in Visual Studio changes color if I click on it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I click on the SQL code than the color of the text changes.

Question: Why it do it? And how to deactive it?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkwsq.png)

Comment: It looks like it's highlighting it to indicate that it's all one statement.

Comment: Is it possible to deactive? Its very distracting.